# Understanding a circuit containing PMOS and NMOS

Tags: transistors, homework

I have the following circuit, the top is a PMOSFET, bottom is NMOSFET

[image]

I'm having troubles understanding what exactly is happening here. I've dealt with PMOSFETs and NMOSFETs separately, and here combined, it seems as though I have no idea as to how to approach this.

Let's say I ground \$V_{\text{in}}\$ (=0), then is the difference in voltage from \$V_{\text{in}}\$ to the top of the PMOS 2.5V? and vice versa with the NMOS? How does that affect \$V_{\text{out}}\$ and the rest of the currents running through the circuit?

I'm not looking for answers, but rather, a way to understand what goes on here.

Comment: It sounds like you actually haven't internalized the very basic idea of *potential difference*.  Yes, if one node is at 0 V (relative to "ground") and another is at 2.5 V, the difference between them is 2.5 V.

Comment: When I say "basic" I mean it's important to understand this in order to understand just about everything else in EE, not "you're dumb if you don't understand it".

Comment: Look at it separately.  Because what activates one, dactivates the other.  It is an invertor.

Comment: Wow. This looks like a NOT gate ;)

Comment: It not a NOT gate because the gnd is not at 0V but at -2.5 V !

Answer (score 1):

**inverting amplifier**

To understand what is happening it is better not to apply a static voltage to \$V_{\text{in}}\$ but instead a Sinus

Think about what is happening while the Voltage is rising from 0V to peak 
(The n-Mosfet is "opening" as the voltage is rising and so your \$V_{\text{out}}\$ is getting more "Negative)

And than again what is happening while the Voltage is falling
(Now the p-Mosfet is doing the same thing as previously the n-Mosfet and   the n-Mosfet is now "blocking" the negative Voltage)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the loadlines, for NMOS and for PMOS

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5i5gS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>